# How to change style based on sibling child attribute

Tags: css, vue.js, css-selectors, stylus, vuetify.js

I'm working with `Vuetify` and `Stylus` on this snipped of HTML

```
<div class="input-group input-group--dirty input-group--text-field">
    <label>Language</label>
    <div class="input-group__input">
        <input readonly="readonly" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group__details"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a `CSS`/`Stylus` way to edit `input-group__details` based on what the status of `input[readonly]` is?

Something like:

```
if (.input-group > input has readonly)
    .input-group__details
        height: 0px

else
    .input-group__details
        height: 5px
```

Basically, how do I change a class based on the sibling's child attribute?

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be done in CSS, and as all CSS preprocessors need to generate CSS, it also cannot be done with any pre- or post-processing whatsoever. You will either have to change your HTML structure, or resort to Javascript. If you have enough time, you can also wait for selectors level 4 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately as of now, this cannot be achieved in CSS, and as all CSS preprocessors need to generate CSS, it also cannot be done with any pre- or post-processing whatsoever.

You will either have to change your HTML structure (make sure the targeted element comes after the readonly input, and they share the parent element), or resort to Javascript.

If you have enough time, you can also wait for **[selectors level 4](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)** to arrive.

which would solve your problem with this

`.input-group__input:has(input[readonly]) + .input-group__details { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Well not possible with the provided markup, but if you allowed to change some markup you can get this...try to make the `.input-group__details` next sibling of `input`..

Also you don't need to assign a value to readonly...just use `readonly`

```css
input[readonly]+.input-group__details {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group input-group--dirty input-group--text-field">
  <label>Language</label>
  <input class="input-group__input" type="text" readonly />
  <div class="input-group__details">Welcome</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group input-group--dirty input-group--text-field">
  <label>Language</label>
  <input class="input-group__input" type="text" />
  <div class="input-group__details">Welcome</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `input[readonly]+.input-group__details` is enough as the mere presence of the attribute makes it readonly. Doesn't matter what you assign to it, so even `<input readonly="false" ... />` will be readonly. Thus it is okay to omit the (redundant) attribute value and go `<input readonly ... />` which is the preferred way of doing in in the sense of DRY.

Comment: I ended up implementing something similar, but I think the correct answer to anyone with a similar question to mine is @connexo

Answer (score 0):

You can bind class.

```
<div class="input-group input-group--dirty input-group--text-field" :class="'className': trueFalse">
    <label>Language</label>
    <div class="input-group__input">
        <input readonly="readonly" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group__details"></div>
</div>
```

Now in your vue script:

```
data: {
    trueFalse: false,
},
methods: {
    someClassName() {
        //condition of your input field
        //if condition true make 'trueFalse' to true else to false
        this.trueFalse = true
    }
}
```

at last in your css:

```
.className {
    //add your style with !important
}
```

Comment: I need a re-usable way achieving that result. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: You can bind style too. <div v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor }"></div>

Now you can re-use the activeColor.